# How to get a Combo box to output into text boxes after item selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox

What I'd like to do is once the user has selected an item from the combo box, for it to then populate the text boxes with the corresponding data.

The error's I'm getting are:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' has
>   some invalid arguments

and

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'

Here is a section of my code:

```
List<Venue> Ven = new List<Venue>();

    private void cboVenue_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            txtVenue.Text = Ven[cboVenue.SelectedItem].m_VenName;

        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Please, any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No, he has 1 reputation and the post was edited by someone with 20K reputation.

Comment: oh.. i thought he was.. im new here like 5 days ago

Comment: And why does it matter how much rep he has? Sometimes you have complete brainfreezes and miss stuff like this, if you're new to the language you might not see right away that you're using the wrong attribute as indexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem. it's integer.

```
List<Venue> Ven = new List<Venue>();

private void cboVenue_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        txtVenue.Text = Ven[cboVenue.SelectedIndex].m_VenName;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did work, silly little thing that went over my head. again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using databinding (or even if you are populating the combobox manually), just use databinding anyways...

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ven}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, ElementName=cmbBox}" />
```

Note that you want to grab the SelectedValue, not the SelectedIndex or SelectedItem. Though, depending on how you setup your combobox the SelectedItem might be equivalent to the SelectedValue... still, use SelectedValue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    txtVenue.Text = Ven[cboVenue.SelectedIndex].m_VenName;
```

You also have to check that the Index is >= 0, an Index of -1 is for "nothing selected"

Comment: why do you cast an integer to integer?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace:

```
txtVenue.Text = Ven[cboVenue.SelectedItem].m_VenName;
```

with:

```
txtVenue.Text = Ven[cboVenue.SelectedIndex].m_VenName;
```

Comment: @PhilipBadilla no, I edited the question for some formatting but I did not ask it...

Answer (score 0):

A combobox's SelectedItem property is an **object** not an **int**.  So when you try to access an item in your list you're getting the error.

If you have bound the data to the combobox such that SelectedItem does contain the list index value (but just as an object) all you need to do is cast it to an int and **then** use it to find the value in your list.

Eg

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(cboVenue.SelectedItem)
```

Then Ven[index] will contain what you need.

Alternatively you may need to look at the SelectedText, SelectedValue or Selectedindex properties of the combobox to work back to the value you require.